# On resize "GET WIDTH" and set "FUNCTION"

Tags: jquery

im trying to create a function, where i want to be able to get `window width` everytime when i resize `window` and then check the width by a `if statemen` and use equal function.. also when is `window width` more than `991px` i need to clear the code for less than `991px` but im not sure if there is any way to use `preventDefault()` ..

And for getting **width** after **resize** i used this code:

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  var winresize = $(window).width();
});
```

but i need to have the **width** value for **if** statement..

**I got this code:**

```js
    function onwinResize() {
        var winresize = $(window).width();

        if(winresize >= 991) {

        }
        else {
            $('.trends').hide();
            $('.trending').click(function() {
                $('.trending').hide();
                $(this).show();
                $('.trends').slideDown();
                $('#back-btn').show();
                $('#search-btn').hide();
            });

            $('#back-btn').click(function() {
              $('.trending').slideDown();
              $('.trends').slideUp();
              $('#back-btn').hide();
              $('#search-btn').show();
            });
        } 
    }
```

Comment: preventDefault() would just stop the event from bubble up. why do you need preventDefault() ?

Comment: @DinoMyte: Because when i resize window(browser) under 991px and resize it back it function what should be just for under 991px are still there.. i need these values be default like for more than 991px "desktop"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your variable `winresize` as a global variable. Then you would be able to read the latest size of the window in your `if` statement:

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrxYOV) - just set up to **`height()`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var winresize = 0;

  $(window).resize(function() {
    winresize = $(window).width();
    onwinResize(winresize);
  });

});

function onwinResize(winresize) {

    if(winresize >= 991) {

    }
    else {

    } 
}
```

Comment: I cant do that like that.. because i will get empty variable not a variable in the `resize` function.. I gonna receive `undefined`..

Comment: @LiborZahrádka: Add this line of code right after `var winresize;`
`$(window).trigger('resize');` it should work like this

Comment: **1.** if u did variable `winresize` inside function `$(document).ready`, so that is the **global variable** for equal function and here is it for  `$(document).ready` function ..

**2.** the global variable `var winresize;` what u did there is a just variable without nothing and if u call it in `.resize(function)` its not gonna be equal to `global variable` its just inside that function..

**3.** dont really understand that code `$(window).trigger("resize");`
because its for nothing there..

Comment: @LiborZahrádka: You are right, pass the variable as input to the function.

Comment: Ok i gonna try it later.. Im not on pc now

Comment: I look at your edited code.. but still it cant work like that..
U set a global variable `var winresize;` (thats fine) then > u place that variable to function `$(window).resize(function()` + u set equal that variable to `$(window).width();` but its in another function so the global variable is still empty so if i gonna call that variable `winresize` i gonna get a `undefined` in console..

Comment: where do you call onwinResize() function? Isn't it somewhere in your document ready statement?

Comment: @LiborZahrádka: The way I handles variable works just fine. I do not know exactly where you call that function but it just does not matter where in the document ready you call it, it should be perfectly fine. I have created a working example here, check this out: http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/PZEKLE

Comment: I add there console log with that variable and there still 'undefined' value.. I gonna check that tomorrow and let u know.. But really thanks for your help man.. Appreciate that

Comment: @LiborZahrádka: "winresize" is bounded with "height" of the document. You can change it to width if you want. Since it is inside the codepen frame, it depends on what view you are currently using. Try to change the height inside of the result section to see the changes.

Comment: Yeah perfectly works.. thanks a lot.. but your code here what u pase into a answer is incorrect.. The **codepen** is right..